# how cross compiled qt5.12.8 + cross compiled grpc1.48.x

Tags: qt, x86-64, grpc, arm64

## What os and version?

```
user@user-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/grpc/cmake/build_arm$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
user@user-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/grpc/cmake/build_arm$
```

```
user@user-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/cmake/build_arm$ uname -a
Linux user-virtual-machine 5.15.0-78-generic #85~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 17 09:42:39 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## How did you install qt?

`./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.12.8.run`

## How did you cross compile qt?

**1.edit qmake.conf**

```
user@user-virtual-machine:~/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++$ cat qmake.conf 
#
# qmake configuration for building with aarch64-linux-gnu-g++
#

MAKEFILE_GENERATOR      = UNIX
CONFIG                 += incremental
QMAKE_INCREMENTAL_STYLE = sublib

include(../common/linux.conf)
include(../common/gcc-base-unix.conf)
include(../common/g++-unix.conf)

# modifications to g++.conf
QMAKE_CC                = /opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
QMAKE_CXX               = /opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++
QMAKE_LINK              = /opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++
QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB        = /opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++

# modifications to linux.conf
QMAKE_AR                = /opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ar cqs
QMAKE_OBJCOPY           = /opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-objcopy
QMAKE_NM                = /opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-nm -P
QMAKE_STRIP             = /opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-strip
load(qt_config)
user@user-virtual-machine:~/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/Src/qtbase/mkspecs/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++$
```

**2.edit build.sh**

```
user@user-virtual-machine:~/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/Src/build$ cat build.sh 
#! /bin/bash
../configure \
-prefix /opt/qt-5.12.8-linux-aarch64-gcc/ \
-opensource \
-confirm-license \
-release \
-xplatform aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ \
-make libs \
-nomake examples \
-nomake tools \
-nomake tests \
-no-openssl \
-no-opengl \
-skip qt3d \
-skip qtactiveqt \
-skip qtandroidextras \
-skip qtcharts \
-skip qtconnectivity \
-skip qtdatavis3d \
-skip qtdeclarative \
-skip qtdoc \
-skip qtgamepad \
-skip qtgraphicaleffects \
-skip qtimageformats \
-skip qtlocation \
-skip qtmacextras \
-skip qtmultimedia \
-skip qtnetworkauth \
-skip qtpurchasing \
-skip qtquickcontrols \
-skip qtquickcontrols2 \
-skip qtremoteobjects \
-skip qtscript \
-skip qtscxml \
-skip qtsensors \
-skip qtserialbus \
-skip qtserialport \
-skip qtspeech \
-skip qtsvg \
-skip qttools \
-skip qttranslations \
-skip qtvirtualkeyboard \
-skip qtwayland \
-skip qtwebchannel \
-skip qtwebglplugin \
-skip qtwebsockets \
-skip qtwebview \
-skip qtwinextras \
-skip qtx11extras \
-skip qtxmlpatterns
```

**3../build.sh,make -j4,make install**

```
user@user-virtual-machine:~/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/Src/build$ ./build.sh 
user@user-virtual-machine:~/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/Src/build$ make -j4
user@user-virtual-machine:~/Qt5.12.8/5.12.8/Src/build$ sudo make install
```

**4.built a qt example project, which could run on arm64 **

## How did you get grpc src?

```
git clone -b v1.48.x https://github.com/grpc/grpc --depth=1
cd grpc
git submodule update --init --depth=1
```

## How did you compile grpc for x86_64?

**1.install ssl**

```
user@user-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/grpc/cmake/build$ sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

**2.cmake **

```
user@user-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/grpc/cmake/build$ cmake \
>   -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
>   -DgRPC_INSTALL=ON \
>   -DgRPC_BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
>   -DgRPC_SSL_PROVIDER=package \
>   -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17 ../..
```

**3.make install**

```
user@user-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/grpc/cmake/build$ sudo make -j4 install
```

## How did cross compile grpc for arm64?

**1.Write a toolchain file**

```
user@user-virtual-machine:/tmp$ cat toolchain.cmake 
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR aarch64)
set(CMAKE_STAGING_PREFIX /tmp/stage)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER /opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /opt/gcc-linaro-7.5.0-2019.12-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
user@user-virtual-machine:/tmp$
```

**2.cmake**

```
user@user-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/grpc/cmake/build_arm$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/tmp/toolchain.cmake \
>       -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
>       -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/tmp/install \
>       -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17 ../..
```

**3.make install**

```
user@user-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/grpc/cmake/build_arm$ make -j4 install
```

## How did you cross compile helloworld?

**1.cmake**

```
user@user-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/cmake/build_arm$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/tmp/toolchain.cmake \
>       -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
>       -Dabsl_DIR=/tmp/stage/lib/cmake/absl \
>       -DProtobuf_DIR=/tmp/stage/lib/cmake/protobuf \
>       -DgRPC_DIR=/tmp/stage/lib/cmake/grpc \
>       -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17 ../..
```

**2.make**

```
user@user-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/cmake/build_arm$ make -j4
```

**3.test**

*3.1 ./greeter_server*

```
user@user-desktop:~/noobTest$ uname -a
Linux user-desktop 5.10.104-tegra #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 15 23:25:51 PDT 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
user@user-desktop:~/noobTest$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
user@user-desktop:~/noobTest$ ./greeter_server 
Server listening on 0.0.0.0:50051
```

*3.2 ./greeter_client*

```
user@user-desktop:~/noobTest$ ./greeter_client 
Greeter received: Hello world
user@user-desktop:~/noobTest$ uname -a
Linux user-desktop 5.10.104-tegra #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Sep 15 23:25:51 PDT 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
user@user-desktop:~/noobTest$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
user@user-desktop:~/noobTest$
```

## Try to use grpc in qt

**1.created a qt console project**
**2.Copied 5 file (listed below)**

```
user@user-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/cmake/build_arm$ ll | grep hello
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user     4412 8月   1 15:54 helloworld.grpc.pb.cc
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    13965 8月   1 15:54 helloworld.grpc.pb.h
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    20072 8月   1 15:54 helloworld.pb.cc
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    18439 8月   1 15:54 helloworld.pb.h

user@user-virtual-machine:~/Downloads/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld$ ll | grep greeter_server.cc 
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user 2398 8月   1 10:21 greeter_server.cc
```

**3.to this dir(greeter_server.cc is renamed as greeter_server.h)**

```
user@user-virtual-machine:~/qtproj/testGrpc$ ll
total 116
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user  4096 8月   1 16:09 ./
drwxrwxr-x 4 user user  4096 8月   1 16:09 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  2406 8月   1 16:08 greeter_server.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  4412 8月   1 15:54 helloworld.grpc.pb.cc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 13965 8月   1 15:54 helloworld.grpc.pb.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 20072 8月   1 15:54 helloworld.pb.cc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 18439 8月   1 15:54 helloworld.pb.h
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user   176 8月   1 16:09 main.cpp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user  1024 8月   1 16:08 testGrpc.pro
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 28917 8月   1 16:05 testGrpc.pro.user
user@user-virtual-machine:~/qtproj/testGrpc$
```

**4.Comment main() in greeter_server.h，edit main.cpp as below**

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include "greeter_server.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    (void)argc;
    (void)argv;


    RunServer();

//    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

//    return a.exec();
}
```

**5. met 3 issues**

```
In file included from ../testGrpc/helloworld.grpc.pb.cc:5:0:
../testGrpc/helloworld.pb.h:10:10: fatal error: google/protobuf/port_def.inc: No such file or directory
 #include <google/protobuf/port_def.inc>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
In file included from ../testGrpc/helloworld.pb.cc:4:0:
../testGrpc/helloworld.pb.h:10:10: fatal error: google/protobuf/port_def.inc: No such file or directory
 #include <google/protobuf/port_def.inc>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:335: helloworld.pb.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [Makefile:332: helloworld.grpc.pb.o] Error 1
In file included from ../testGrpc/main.cpp:3:0:
../testGrpc/greeter_server.h:23:10: fatal error: grpcpp/ext/proto_server_reflection_plugin.h: No such file or directory
 #include <grpcpp/ext/proto_server_reflection_plugin.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

**6.add INCLUDEPATH in testGrpc.pro,rebuild**

```
INCLUDEPATH += /tmp/stage/include
```

**7.met 197 issues**

```
helloworld.grpc.pb.o: In function `google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyOutputStream::ZeroCopyOutputStream()':
/tmp/stage/include/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.h:186: undefined reference to `vtable for google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyOutputStream'
/tmp/stage/include/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.h:186: undefined reference to `vtable for google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyOutputStream'
helloworld.grpc.pb.o: In function `google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyOutputStream::~ZeroCopyOutputStream()':
/tmp/stage/include/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.h:187: undefined reference to `vtable for google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyOutputStream'
/tmp/stage/include/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.h:187: undefined reference to `vtable for google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyOutputStream'
helloworld.grpc.pb.o: In function `grpc::Slice::~Slice()':
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/slice.h:41: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/slice.h:41: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/slice.h:41: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/slice.h:41: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
helloworld.grpc.pb.o: In function `grpc::Slice::Slice(unsigned long)':
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/slice.h:54: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
```

**8.List libs in /tmp/stage/lib**

```
user@user-virtual-machine:/tmp/stage/lib$ ll
total 54384
drwxrwxr-x 4 user user     4096 8月   1 15:48 ./
drwxrwxr-x 6 user user     4096 8月   1 15:48 ../
drwxrwxr-x 7 user user     4096 8月   1 15:48 cmake/
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     1148 8月   1 15:31 libabsl_bad_any_cast_impl.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     1162 8月   1 15:33 libabsl_bad_optional_access.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     1162 8月   1 15:31 libabsl_bad_variant_access.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    22906 8月   1 15:33 libabsl_base.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     4596 8月   1 15:33 libabsl_city.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    29766 8月   1 15:28 libabsl_civil_time.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   102822 8月   1 15:35 libabsl_cord.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   130536 8月   1 15:34 libabsl_cord_internal.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     4148 8月   1 15:31 libabsl_cordz_functions.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    13014 8月   1 15:35 libabsl_cordz_handle.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    18182 8月   1 15:35 libabsl_cordz_info.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     3806 8月   1 15:35 libabsl_cordz_sample_token.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    26438 8月   1 15:33 libabsl_debugging_internal.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    48644 8月   1 15:33 libabsl_demangle_internal.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     6280 8月   1 15:34 libabsl_examine_stack.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     2962 8月   1 15:28 libabsl_exponential_biased.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    12156 8月   1 15:34 libabsl_failure_signal_handler.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     1060 8月   1 15:35 libabsl_flags.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     3884 8月   1 15:34 libabsl_flags_commandlineflag.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     3934 8月   1 15:30 libabsl_flags_commandlineflag_internal.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    25492 8月   1 15:35 libabsl_flags_config.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    43884 8月   1 15:35 libabsl_flags_internal.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    45812 8月   1 15:34 libabsl_flags_marshalling.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    87010 8月   1 15:35 libabsl_flags_parse.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     3572 8月   1 15:34 libabsl_flags_private_handle_accessor.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     8480 8月   1 15:35 libabsl_flags_program_name.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    53454 8月   1 15:35 libabsl_flags_reflection.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     5908 8月   1 15:35 libabsl_flags_usage.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    70532 8月   1 15:35 libabsl_flags_usage_internal.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    46556 8月   1 15:34 libabsl_graphcycles_internal.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     3966 8月   1 15:34 libabsl_hash.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    14502 8月   1 15:35 libabsl_hashtablez_sampler.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    21632 8月   1 15:28 libabsl_int128.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     2762 8月   1 15:30 libabsl_leak_check.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     3666 8月   1 15:28 libabsl_log_severity.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     2064 8月   1 15:33 libabsl_low_level_hash.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    24210 8月   1 15:33 libabsl_malloc_internal.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     5164 8月   1 15:30 libabsl_periodic_sampler.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    12782 8月   1 15:33 libabsl_random_distributions.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    24340 8月   1 15:34 libabsl_random_internal_distribution_test_util.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     5928 8月   1 15:28 libabsl_random_internal_platform.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    27320 8月   1 15:34 libabsl_random_internal_pool_urbg.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     3626 8月   1 15:33 libabsl_random_internal_randen.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     1786 8月   1 15:33 libabsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     3282 8月   1 15:31 libabsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes_impl.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     8288 8月   1 15:31 libabsl_random_internal_randen_slow.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     4676 8月   1 15:33 libabsl_random_internal_seed_material.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     5880 8月   1 15:28 libabsl_random_seed_gen_exception.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     3200 8月   1 15:34 libabsl_random_seed_sequences.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     3722 8月   1 15:35 libabsl_raw_hash_set.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     7714 8月   1 15:31 libabsl_raw_logging_internal.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     4992 8月   1 15:31 libabsl_scoped_set_env.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     3098 8月   1 15:28 libabsl_spinlock_wait.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     9546 8月   1 15:33 libabsl_stacktrace.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    47954 8月   1 15:35 libabsl_status.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    16346 8月   1 15:35 libabsl_statusor.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     5032 8月   1 15:28 libabsl_strerror.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   156284 8月   1 15:34 libabsl_str_format_internal.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   212922 8月   1 15:33 libabsl_strings.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    17208 8月   1 15:33 libabsl_strings_internal.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    33168 8月   1 15:34 libabsl_symbolize.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    87972 8月   1 15:34 libabsl_synchronization.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    18208 8月   1 15:33 libabsl_throw_delegate.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   107554 8月   1 15:34 libabsl_time.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   216838 8月   1 15:28 libabsl_time_zone.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    10048 8月   1 15:28 libaddress_sorting.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   183502 8月   1 15:28 libcares.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  2613838 8月   1 15:32 libcrypto.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   141912 8月   1 15:35 libgpr.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  2498248 8月   1 15:48 libgrpc++.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 17382700 8月   1 15:47 libgrpc.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user    44186 8月   1 15:48 libgrpc++_alts.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user     1148 8月   1 15:48 libgrpc++_error_details.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   982068 8月   1 15:35 libgrpc_plugin_support.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1093866 8月   1 15:48 libgrpcpp_channelz.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   746920 8月   1 15:48 libgrpc++_reflection.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1546716 8月   1 15:44 libgrpc++_unsecure.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  9981064 8月   1 15:42 libgrpc_unsecure.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  6006370 8月   1 15:30 libprotobuf.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1313398 8月   1 15:31 libprotobuf-lite.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  6637854 8月   1 15:35 libprotoc.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  1181922 8月   1 15:29 libre2.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   829880 8月   1 15:30 libssl.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   190942 8月   1 15:28 libupb.a
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user   151918 8月   1 15:28 libz.a
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user    12288 8月   1 15:48 pkgconfig/
user@user-virtual-machine:/tmp/stage/lib$
```

**9.Add LIBS in testGrpc.pro,rebuild**

```
INCLUDEPATH += /tmp/stage/include
LIBS += -L/tmp/stage/lib/ \
-lprotobuf
```

**10.met 58 issues**

```
helloworld.grpc.pb.o: In function `grpc::Slice::~Slice()':
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/slice.h:41: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/slice.h:41: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/slice.h:41: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/slice.h:41: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
helloworld.grpc.pb.o: In function `grpc::Slice::Slice(unsigned long)':
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/slice.h:54: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
helloworld.grpc.pb.o:/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/slice.h:54: more undefined references to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface' follow
helloworld.grpc.pb.o: In function `grpc::GrpcLibraryCodegen::GrpcLibraryCodegen(bool)':
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:45: undefined reference to `grpc::g_glip'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:45: undefined reference to `grpc::g_glip'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:45: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:45: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:45: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:45: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:48: undefined reference to `grpc::g_glip'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:48: undefined reference to `grpc::g_glip'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:48: undefined reference to `grpc::g_glip'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:48: undefined reference to `grpc::g_glip'
helloworld.grpc.pb.o: In function `grpc::GrpcLibraryCodegen::~GrpcLibraryCodegen()':
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:54: undefined reference to `grpc::g_glip'
helloworld.grpc.pb.o:/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:54: more undefined references to `grpc::g_glip' follow
helloworld.grpc.pb.o: In function `grpc::GrpcLibraryCodegen::~GrpcLibraryCodegen()':
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:54: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:54: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:54: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:54: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:57: undefined reference to `grpc::g_glip'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:57: undefined reference to `grpc::g_glip'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:57: undefined reference to `grpc::g_glip'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/grpc_library.h:57: undefined reference to `grpc::g_glip'
helloworld.grpc.pb.o: In function `grpc::internal::MethodHandler::Deserialize(grpc_call*, grpc_byte_buffer*, grpc::Status*, void**)':
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/rpc_service_method.h:80: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/rpc_service_method.h:80: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/rpc_service_method.h:80: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/rpc_service_method.h:80: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
helloworld.grpc.pb.o: In function `grpc::CompletionQueue::~CompletionQueue()':
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/completion_queue.h:120: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
helloworld.grpc.pb.o:/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/completion_queue.h:120: more undefined references to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface' follow
helloworld.grpc.pb.o: In function `grpc::CompletionQueue::~CompletionQueue()':
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/completion_queue.h:119: undefined reference to `absl::lts_20220623::Mutex::~Mutex()'
helloworld.grpc.pb.o: In function `grpc::CompletionQueue::CompletionQueue(grpc_completion_queue_attributes const&)':
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/completion_queue.h:254: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/completion_queue.h:254: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/completion_queue.h:257: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/completion_queue.h:257: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/completion_queue.h:254: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
helloworld.grpc.pb.o:/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/completion_queue.h:254: more undefined references to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface' follow
helloworld.grpc.pb.o: In function `grpc::CompletionQueue::CompletionQueue(grpc_completion_queue_attributes const&)':
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/completion_queue.h:253: undefined reference to `absl::lts_20220623::Mutex::~Mutex()'
helloworld.grpc.pb.o: In function `grpc::CompletionQueue::Pluck(grpc::internal::CompletionQueueTag*)':
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/completion_queue.h:326: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/completion_queue.h:326: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/completion_queue.h:326: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/completion_queue.h:326: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/completion_queue.h:329: undefined reference to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface'
helloworld.grpc.pb.o:/tmp/stage/include/grpcpp/impl/codegen/completion_queue.h:329: more undefined references to `grpc::g_core_codegen_interface' follow
main.o: In function `RunServer()':
/home/user/qtproj/build-testGrpc-qt5_12_8_arm64-Debug/../testGrpc/greeter_server.h:57: undefined reference to `grpc::EnableDefaultHealthCheckService(bool)'
/home/user/qtproj/build-testGrpc-qt5_12_8_arm64-Debug/../testGrpc/greeter_server.h:58: undefined reference to `grpc::reflection::InitProtoReflectionServerBuilderPlugin()'
/home/user/qtproj/build-testGrpc-qt5_12_8_arm64-Debug/../testGrpc/greeter_server.h:59: undefined reference to `grpc::ServerBuilder::ServerBuilder()'
/home/user/qtproj/build-testGrpc-qt5_12_8_arm64-Debug/../testGrpc/greeter_server.h:61: undefined reference to `grpc::InsecureServerCredentials()'
/home/user/qtproj/build-testGrpc-qt5_12_8_arm64-Debug/../testGrpc/greeter_server.h:61: undefined reference to `grpc::ServerBuilder::AddListeningPort(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::shared_ptr<grpc::ServerCredentials>, int*)'
/home/user/qtproj/build-testGrpc-qt5_12_8_arm64-Debug/../testGrpc/greeter_server.h:64: undefined reference to `grpc::ServerBuilder::RegisterService(grpc::Service*)'
/home/user/qtproj/build-testGrpc-qt5_12_8_arm64-Debug/../testGrpc/greeter_server.h:66: undefined reference to `grpc::ServerBuilder::BuildAndStart()'
/home/user/qtproj/build-testGrpc-qt5_12_8_arm64-Debug/../testGrpc/greeter_server.h:59: undefined reference to `grpc::ServerBuilder::~ServerBuilder()'
/home/user/qtproj/build-testGrpc-qt5_12_8_arm64-Debug/../testGrpc/greeter_server.h:59: undefined reference to `grpc::ServerBuilder::~ServerBuilder()'
main.o: In function `GreeterServiceImpl::SayHello(grpc::ServerContext*, helloworld::HelloRequest const*, helloworld::HelloReply*)':
/home/user/qtproj/build-testGrpc-qt5_12_8_arm64-Debug/../testGrpc/greeter_server.h:49: undefined reference to `grpc::Status::OK'
/home/user/qtproj/build-testGrpc-qt5_12_8_arm64-Debug/../testGrpc/greeter_server.h:49: undefined reference to `grpc::Status::OK'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:137: testGrpc] Error 1
16:44:40: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project testGrpc (kit: qt5.12.8_arm64)
The kit qt5.12.8_arm64 has configuration issues which might be the root cause for this problem.
When executing step "Make"
16:44:40: Elapsed time: 00:07.
```

**11.Add LIBS in testGrpc.pro,rebuild**

```
INCLUDEPATH += /tmp/stage/include
LIBS += -L/tmp/stage/lib/ \
-lprotobuf \
-lgrpc
```

**12.met 13822 issues, some issues reported early is pasted below**

```
/tmp/stage/lib//libgrpc.a(retry_filter.cc.o): In function `grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::RetryFilter::CallData::CallStackDestructionBarrier::~CallStackDestructionBarrier()':
retry_filter.cc:(.text+0x68): undefined reference to `absl::lts_20220623::Status::UnrefNonInlined(unsigned long)'
/tmp/stage/lib//libgrpc.a(retry_filter.cc.o): In function `grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::RetryFilter::CallData::FailPendingBatchInCallCombiner(void*, absl::lts_20220623::Status)':
retry_filter.cc:(.text+0xb4): undefined reference to `absl::lts_20220623::Status::UnrefNonInlined(unsigned long)'
retry_filter.cc:(.text+0xec): undefined reference to `absl::lts_20220623::Status::UnrefNonInlined(unsigned long)'
/tmp/stage/lib//libgrpc.a(retry_filter.cc.o): In function `grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::RetryFilter::CallData::CallAttempt::OnPerAttemptRecvTimer(void*, absl::lts_20220623::Status)':
retry_filter.cc:(.text+0x144): undefined reference to `absl::lts_20220623::Status::UnrefNonInlined(unsigned long)'
retry_filter.cc:(.text+0x17c): undefined reference to `absl::lts_20220623::Status::UnrefNonInlined(unsigned long)'
/tmp/stage/lib//libgrpc.a(retry_filter.cc.o):retry_filter.cc:(.text+0x1cc): more undefined references to `absl::lts_20220623::Status::UnrefNonInlined(unsigned long)' follow
/tmp/stage/lib//libgrpc.a(retry_filter.cc.o): In function `grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::RetryFilter::CallData::MaybeClearPendingBatch(grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::RetryFilter::CallData::PendingBatch*)':
retry_filter.cc:(.text+0x3c8): undefined reference to `gpr_log'
/tmp/stage/lib//libgrpc.a(retry_filter.cc.o): In function `grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::RetryFilter::CallData::CallStackDestructionBarrier::~CallStackDestructionBarrier()':
retry_filter.cc:(.text+0x4ec): undefined reference to `absl::lts_20220623::Status::UnrefNonInlined(unsigned long)'
/tmp/stage/lib//libgrpc.a(retry_filter.cc.o): In function `grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::RetryFilter::CallData::CallStackDestructionBarrier::OnLbCallDestructionComplete(void*, absl::lts_20220623::Status)':
retry_filter.cc:(.text+0x6fc): undefined reference to `absl::lts_20220623::Status::UnrefNonInlined(unsigned long)'
/tmp/stage/lib//libgrpc.a(retry_filter.cc.o): In function `grpc_core::(anonymous namespace)::RetryFilter::CallData::CallAttempt::ShouldRetry(std::optional<grpc_status_code>, std::optional<grpc_core::Duration>)':
retry_filter.cc:(.text+0x8c8): undefined reference to `gpr_log'
retry_filter.cc:(.text+0x934): undefined reference to `gpr_log'
retry_filter.cc:(.text+0x970): undefined reference to `gpr_log'
retry_filter.cc:(.text+0x9b8): undefined reference to `gpr_log'
retry_filter.cc:(.text+0xa30): undefined reference to `gpr_log'
/tmp/stage/lib//libgrpc.a(retry_filter.cc.o):retry_filter.cc:(.text+0xa64): more undefined references to `gpr_log' follow
```

## What problem and what you need?

the problem is that i do not know the order of grpc lib to add in .pro file.
what i need is build a qt project successfully supported by cross compiled grpc with cross compiled qmake.

This is my first post, hope i have introduced the problem clearly.Any helps will be greatly appreciated.

I tried quote all libs in /tmp/stage/lib ,but met thousands issues.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is what order of grpc libs should be add in .pro file. what I need is building a qt project successfully supported by cross compiled grpc with cross compiled qmake.

Answer (score 0):

i found something in file /home/user/Downloads/grpc/examples/cpp/helloworld/MakeFile.

> LDFLAGS += -L/usr/local/lib `pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++`
> -pthread
> -lgrpc++_reflection
> -ldl

then i execute command below in the end.

```
pkg-config --libs protobuf grpc++
```

output:

> -L/usr/local/lib -lprotobuf -pthread -lgrpc++ -lgrpc -laddress_sorting -lre2 -lupb -lcares -lz -lgpr -lssl -lcrypto -labsl_raw_hash_set -labsl_hashtablez_sampler -labsl_hash -labsl_city -labsl_low_level_hash -labsl_random_distributions -labsl_random_seed_sequences -labsl_random_internal_pool_urbg -labsl_random_internal_randen -labsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes -labsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes_impl -labsl_random_internal_randen_slow -labsl_random_internal_platform -labsl_random_internal_seed_material -labsl_random_seed_gen_exception -labsl_statusor -labsl_status -labsl_cord -labsl_cordz_info -labsl_cord_internal -labsl_cordz_functions -labsl_exponential_biased -labsl_cordz_handle -labsl_bad_optional_access -labsl_strerror -labsl_str_format_internal -labsl_synchronization -labsl_graphcycles_internal -labsl_stacktrace -labsl_symbolize -labsl_debugging_internal -labsl_demangle_internal -labsl_malloc_internal -labsl_time -labsl_civil_time -labsl_strings -labsl_strings_internal -lrt -labsl_base -labsl_spinlock_wait -labsl_int128 -labsl_throw_delegate -labsl_time_zone -labsl_bad_variant_access -labsl_raw_logging_internal -labsl_log_severity

i copied the output into testGrpc.pro, modified the dirctory of libs ,now the whole testGrpc.pro file:

> QT -= gui
>
> CONFIG += c++17 console CONFIG -= app_bundle
>
> DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS
>
> SOURCES += 
> helloworld.grpc.pb.cc 
> helloworld.pb.cc 
> main.cpp
>
> qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin else: unix:!android:
> target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin !isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS +=
> target
>
> HEADERS += 
> greeter_server.h 
> helloworld.grpc.pb.h 
> helloworld.pb.h
>
> INCLUDEPATH += /tmp/stage/include LIBS +=  -L/tmp/stage/lib -lprotobuf
> -pthread -lgrpc++ -lgrpc -laddress_sorting -lre2 -lupb -lcares -lz -lgpr -lssl -lcrypto -labsl_raw_hash_set -labsl_hashtablez_sampler -labsl_hash -labsl_city -labsl_low_level_hash -labsl_random_distributions -labsl_random_seed_sequences -labsl_random_internal_pool_urbg -labsl_random_internal_randen -labsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes -labsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes_impl -labsl_random_internal_randen_slow -labsl_random_internal_platform -labsl_random_internal_seed_material -labsl_random_seed_gen_exception -labsl_statusor -labsl_status -labsl_cord -labsl_cordz_info -labsl_cord_internal -labsl_cordz_functions -labsl_exponential_biased -labsl_cordz_handle -labsl_bad_optional_access -labsl_strerror -labsl_str_format_internal -labsl_synchronization -labsl_graphcycles_internal -labsl_stacktrace -labsl_symbolize -labsl_debugging_internal -labsl_demangle_internal -labsl_malloc_internal -labsl_time -labsl_civil_time -labsl_strings -labsl_strings_internal -lrt -labsl_base -labsl_spinlock_wait -labsl_int128 -labsl_throw_delegate -labsl_time_zone -labsl_bad_variant_access -labsl_raw_logging_internal -labsl_log_severity 
> -pthread 
> -lgrpc++_reflection 
> -ldl

click rebuild,there're no issues.Copy the executable file 'testGrpc' onto ARM64 .it could run normally.

> user@user-desktop:~/noobTest$ ./testGrpc
> Server listening on 0.0.0.0:50051
>
> user@user-desktop:~/noobTest$ ./greeter_client
> Greeter received:Hello world